Развертывание приложения Qt на Linux
В папке имеется исполняемый файл, скрипт для его запуска и папки с плагинами, библиотеками и т.д
Скрипт


#!/bin/sh
dirname="$(dirname "$0")"
appname="$(basename "$0")"

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$dirname/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec "$dirname/$appname" $*



библиотеки видит, ругается на плагины


qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.



как прикрутить плагины и остальное? в папке с исполняемым файлом лежит файл qt.conf с содержимым - ничего не дает


[Paths]
Prefix = ./
Plugins = plugins
Imports = qml
Qml2Imports = qml



